# How do you programmatically go to different tabs?

Tags: iphone

I have tabcontroller have multiple navigation controllers. Touching different tabs will goto different naviagtion controller. How do I programmatically goto different tabs?

Normally, I go there by touching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TabBarController, you can set the selectedViewController property to the view controller of the tab you want to become active:

```
myTabBarController.selectedViewController = aViewController;
```

Alternatively, if you know the index number of the view controller in the TabBarController's viewControllers array, you can set that:

```
myTabBarController.selectedIndex = 2; // selects the third view controller in myTabBarController.viewControllers
```

Comment: Based on my bad experience on using selected Index, i suggest using selectedViewController over selectedIndex. Simply because, in future if you insert any tab before that index, it breaks the UI flow. So safe it to use SelectedViewController.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set value to selectedIndex for your tabViewController `[your tabviewcontroller].selectedIndex = 1;`